# Azure: VM Backup Explained

Tags: backup, virtual-machines, azure

I am working towards my first capture of a Linux Azure VM using the capture tool.

The first step is to run `sudo waagent –deprovision`. Running this command does the following:

> 1. Removes SSH host keys (if Provisioning.RegenerateSshHostKeyPair is 'y' in the configuration file)

Does this mean that my private/public keys will be gone and my existing server will no longer be able to SSH into it's peers without copying these keys back in place?

> 2. Clears nameserver configuration in /etc/resolv.conf

I believe my custom defined DNS names will have to be put back in place as well.

> 3. Removes the root user's password from /etc/shadow (if Provisioning.DeleteRootPassword is 'y' in the configuration file)

Not familiar with `/etc/shadow`. Will I no longer have SSH access to my server?

> 4. Removes cached DHCP client leases

I'm assuming this is harmless.

> 5. Resets host name to localhost.localdomain

I believe this is only an issue if a custom hostname was setup.

> 6. Deletes the last provisioned user account (obtained from /var/lib/waagent) and associated data

Is this an account being provisioned by the capture tool itself or by me? If latter, why so?

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question, you need to understand why you execute command `sudo waagent –deprovision`.

There are two types images: Generalized and Specialized.

For a Generalized image, you should execute `sudo waagent –deprovision`, the commands removes all your personal account information, among other things, and prepares the machine to be used as an image. **But it does not affect your data stored on your VM, only remove things that you mentioned. You could use Generalized image to deploy multiple VMs.**  The command's function is like Windows command [`Sysprep`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/capture-image).

For a Specialized images, on ARM mode, you only need copy VM's VHD to other storage account and use the VHD to re-create a new VM. You don't lose any data on the VM. **But you could use the image to deploy one VM.** So, if you want to use your VM's VHD to deploy multiple VMs, you need to execute `sudo waagent –deprovision`.

I see that CtrlDot has answered your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879454/azure-vm-backup-explained), but I want to add it that, if you want to backup your VM, I suggest you could use [Azure Backup Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup). Capture VM could only backup once, if you want to backup your VM everyday or weekly, you need do it every time.